# How to keep date format when using pandasql?

Tags: python, sql, pandasql

In order to join two dataframes df_A and df_B where a date of df_A should lie between a date range of dataframe df_B I am using pandasql. However i noticed that pandasql does not return a proper date (datetime64) as in the original dataframe but a string (object). Is there an easy way to solve this or do i have to apply a string to date conversion everytime I have executed a query?

```
import pandasql as ps
sql = """select invoice_date from df_A"""
ps.sqldf(sql, locals())
```

I would expect this output to be the same as just `df_A.loc[:,'invoice_date']`

Instead as an example this gives me 
`'2018-01-02 00:00:00.000000'` (as a string) rather than `'2018-01-02'` (as date)

Comment: Is this SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the object datatype to datetime

```
df_A['invoice_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_A['invoice_date'])
```

this will change the dataframe to expected output